# Can't close the "Confirm" screen just after logging in with Facebook in Android

Tags: android, facebook

I'm trying to figure out this issue with Facebook login in my Android app. I don't have the Facebook app installed in my phone, so the app it's using a Webview for the Facebook login. But the same issue happens if I have the Facebook app installed.

So the problem is that after logging with Facebook (previously I clicked the Facebook login button which opens a new layer with the Facebook login form), then I get a "Confirm" window saying:

[image]

If I click "OK", then that window (layer) disappears and immediately appears again. And it's like a loop, since nothing changes clicking the "OK" button, "Cancel" button or just closing the screen on the X icon. It always returns to the "Confirm" screen.

The most strange part is that it works with some users, for example with my personal Facebook account, but not with others, for example with a couple of new Facebook users I created just for testing.

I've tried deleting the data and clearing the cache of the app in my phone, but I still get the same issue.

I'm using the Facebook SDK v3.19 and an old version (v1.0) of the Facebook Login API.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: Check the [docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/android/v2.4). Are you sure that you're registering the callback correctly?

Comment: I'm using the Facebook SDK v3.19 and an old version (v1.0) of Facebook Login API, and actually it works with some users, but not with others. For example, I can log in with my personal Facebook account, but not with a new account that I created just for testing.

Comment: v3.19 is very old try upgrading and see if you are still facing issue.